# Postgres table constraint using group-by

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have a Postgres table that looks like this:

```
Category     Unit          Default Unit
---------------------------------------
Currency     USD           True
Currency     EURO          False
Currency     AUS           False
Length       Kilometer     True
Length       Mile          False
Length       Foot          False
Length       Inch          False
Mass         Kilogram      True
```

I want to set a table constraint so that there can be only one 'Default Unit' per Category.

Can this be done using Group By in a constraint, perhaps?

Comment: No, you can't put `group by` in a constraint.

Comment: Thanks. Can you see any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a unique partial index:

```
create unique index idx_table(category, default_unit) on table(category, default_unit)
    where default_unit;
```

Comment: @Denis . . . That is true.  There just seems to be something more "explicit" about including it in the column list as well as the filtering clause.