# liquibase database refactoring xml createIndex

Tags: xml, postgresql, liquibase

In response to this question: [Postgres table constraint using group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476736/postgres-table-constraint-using-group-by/27476776#27476776),
I'm trying to translate the following Postgres code into liquibase XML

```
create unique index idx_table on table(subcategory, base_unit)
where base_unit;
```

I tried this:

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_table"
    tableName="table"
    unique="true">
    <columnNames="subcategory, base_unit"/>
    <where>base_unit</where>
</createIndex>
```

but that gives me the error:
    Element type "columnNames" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

**UPDATE:**

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_table"
    tableName="table"
    unique="true">
    <column name="subcategory"/>
    <column name="base_unit"/>
    <where>base_unit</where>
</createIndex>
```

results in the error:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element 'where'. One of '{"liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog":column}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liquibase doesn't currently support the "where" portion in createIndex.

You will either need to use modifySql:

```
<changeSet id="YOUR_ID" author="YOU">
    <createIndex indexName="idx_table"
                 tableName="table"
                 unique="true">
        <column name="subcategory"/>
        <column name="base_unit"/>
    </createIndex>
    <modifySql>
        <append value=" where base_unit"/>
    </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

or just use sql directly:

```
<changeSet id="YOUR_ID" author="YOU">
    <sql>create unique index idx_table on table(subcategory, base_unit) where base_unit</sql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your xml should look like this:

```
<createIndex indexName="idx_table"
    tableName="table"
    unique="true">
    <column name="subcategory"/>
    <column name="base_unit"/>
    <where>base_unit</where>
</createIndex>
```